# What to use after DateRange in is deprecated in Pandas after version 0.13.1 (Python )

Tags: python, pandas

here is a python question:
I use DateRange module in pandas (version 0.13.1). The subsequent versions of pandas will not have DateRange.
What is the best way to replicate this functionality of DateRange:

```
DateRange(datetime(2000,1,1),datetime(2001,1,1),useOffset=BDay())

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2000-01-03, ..., 2001-01-01]
Length: 261, Freq: B, Timezone: None
```

Can you do that with with DatetimeIndex?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html?highlight=date_range#pandas.date_range)

```
date_range(datetime(2000,1,1),datetime(2001,1),freq='B')
```

Many options to specify frequency, you can also use `bdate_range` to generate business date ranges.